# Infinite scrolling VirtualTreeView

Tags: delphi, infinite-scroll, vcl, virtualtreeview

Is there a way to implement infinite scrolling using virtualtreeview?

I'd like to load a set number of database records at a time, and add them to the virtualtreeview when the user scrolls down. But I'm not sure how I would trigger the adding of new rows.

Comment: Do you want to only increment node count as the user scrolls down (keeping the vertical scrollbar visible) ? Or you want a scrollbar-less *grid* that will just remember the offset and display the just fetched small block (without vertical scrollbar) ?

Comment: I was hoping to keep the scrollbar visible, such as in http://www.sitepoint.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo4/

Comment: If you have a quick way of determining the number of records, you can set the node count using that. You needn't load the *data* immediately; you can use the `OnInitNode` event to lazily load the records as they're needed.

Comment: How should this feature behave when the control is resized (so its vertical scroll bar disappears) ?

Comment: This isn't a large concern for me personally, since my control is not resizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the `OnScroll` event and check if the scrollbar reached the end this way:

```
type
  // this interposer class is used to publish the RangeY property
  TVirtualStringTree = class(VirtualTrees.TVirtualStringTree)
  public
    property RangeY;
  end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTreeScroll(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; DeltaX,
  DeltaY: Integer);
var
  Tree: TVirtualStringTree;
begin
  // if the vertical scroll occurred, then...
  if DeltaY <> 0 then
  begin
    // just a helper variable
    Tree := TVirtualStringTree(Sender);
    // if the client height without the top offset equals, or exceeds (actually, it should
    // never exceed; just for sure) the virtual tree height, then we reached the bottom of
    // the tree, so...
    if Tree.ClientHeight - Tree.OffsetY >= Integer(Tree.RangeY) then
    begin
      // the scrollbar reached the end of the tree; now fetch your data and add some nodes
      // (ideally as a thread task showing some fancy animation; the following is just for
      // example)
      ShowMessage('Fetch your data...');
      Tree.RootNodeCount := Tree.RootNodeCount + 50;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In the OnResize callback, you can call the same logic as in OnScroll (excluding the DeltaY check). This has the benefit of supporting loading on form resize.